# Disabling R diagnostics for Rmarkdown

Tags: r

Is there a way to disable R diagnostics for RMD file?
I'm running a simple preliminary code here and getting these warnings "Unknown or uninitialized column: xxx".

```
library(readr)
dataset = read_csv("breast_cancer.csv")
is.factor(dataset$cellularity)
is.factor(dataset$cancer_type_detailed)
```

[image]

A quick google search tells me these warnings are common with no way to fix it. At least I would like to know how to disable these in my RMD file. Also don't want to have to write in `warnings=FALSE` for every R chunk.

Link to dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/raghadalharbi/breast-cancer-gene-expression-profiles-metabric

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to suppress these -- they are signals that your code has problems.   If you are just testing a script to see how the formatting looks, why not put together a fake dataset that contains the right column names?

Comment: It seems like this particular warning is very common in R and there doesn't seem to be a known fix for this issue. If you know anything about it and how to actually fix it, I would appreciate your thoughts. I have no idea what's causing it. I'm not even manipulating anything in the above lines of code.

Comment: It means exactly what it says:  `dataset` (which is a tibble) has no columns named `cellularity` or `cancer_type_detailed`.  That's user error.

Comment: That's my mistake this is the dataset. https://www.kaggle.com/raghadalharbi/breast-cancer-gene-expression-profiles-metabric

Comment: How should I add it? Because the dataset is 2500 x 34

Comment: There is a column called `Cellularity`, which is not the same as `cellularity`.  R is case sensitive.  There is one called `Cancer Type Detailed`, not one called `cancer_type_detailed`.

Comment: Yeah that resolves it. For some reason in the original data source  from kaggle column name is described to be `cancer_type`. It's also easier to work with variable names without spaces in between. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually a bad idea to suppress warnings:  very few of them are false positives.  Suppressing them globally is a really bad idea.

In this case, the warnings signal that your `dataset` does not have columns with those names.  From the `str(dataset)` information, we can see that there is a column named `Cellularity` and one named `Cancer Type Detailed`.  Those don't match the names you used in your code, `cellularity` and `cancer_type_detailed`.

If you get a warning like this, you should examine the dataset to see what the names really are.  One way is to print `str(dataset)`; even better is to print `names(dataset)`, which will show very clearly exactly what the names are.

There's one situation where you might not want to see that warning.  If you are not sure if a column is included, you might use a test like

```
if (is.null(dataset$notthere)) { ... }
```

You'll get the warning from this code when `dataset` is a tibble.  The way to avoid it is to use

```
if (is.null(dataset[["notthere"]])) ...
```

or

```
if (! "notthere" %in% names(dataset)) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can globally hide warnings like this:

````r
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
```
````

You add this chunk in the beginning of your Rmarkdown file and warnings are not shown anymore. You can also add other sommon chunk options there if you like.